# Video Scheduler Internal Error

Tags: video, graphics-card, bsod, crash, windows-11

I have an Nvidia GTX 1660ti graphics card which I bought about 3 years ago.
Recently I've been experiencing the "VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR" BSOD.

As soon as I open up chrome, edge or any browser other than tor, the computer freezes and does a BSOD. Sometimes I'm able to get away with a bit more, like watching a YouTube video or similar.
The above has a few caveats though. I cannot watch in full screen or the video sometimes blacks out with audio playing in the background. If I hit escape fast enough (to take it off full screen), the computer won't crash.
When the video is not full screen, the video blacks out for a few fractions of a second.

My graphics design programs like Photoshop, Illustrator and Corel Draw all crash after a few seconds and I can't get any work done unless I disable hardware acceleration. My browsers crash the PC even with hardware acceleration turned off.

My games crash to desktop as well. Sometimes it takes a few seconds, sometimes a few minutes.

All in all the crashes happen frequently but randomly. There are set actions that crash it, but their timings are not the same every time.

Short of reinstalling Windows. I've tried all the below fixes:

- I've disabled fTPM because I thought this might be the problem.
- I've reinstalled my drivers after using DDU to remove them.
- I've checked for malware
- I've done a chkdsk /f /r
- I've air dusted my entire PC.
- I've done an sfc /scannow
- I'm running windows 11 and all my updates are as recent as possible.
- I've reseated my gfx card.

I don't have another card to test with so the closest thing I can do is run Furmark. Furmark on the other hand is happily chugging along even as I type this. No errors, no glitching, no blackness.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my CUDA development drivers. I completely forgot that my CUDA drivers were only compatible with a certain version of the regular Nvidia Drivers.
When I updated my regular drivers, there was a conflict somewhere between the two.
I uninstalled my CUDA drivers and computer is back to working properly.